# PHP's decode64 behaves strangely differently from Ruby's decode64

Tags: php, ruby

Ruby's

`Base64.decode64('OVUP/PZrLzoZpaeQga/TpK9xeJAOuTTbUzm9NplDuhSUMkklPtDeDQDgidUEIX+ijxe80EI').length`

returns 51.

PHP's

`strlen(base64_decode('OVUP/PZrLzoZpaeQga/TpK9xeJAOuTTbUzm9NplDuhSUMkklPtDeDQDgidUEIX+ijxe80EI'))`

returns 53.

Why?

Comment: I suspect this has more to do with how you are determining length.  PHP is just counting bytes, where Ruby might be trying to determine a character type.  I'm not a Ruby coder though... perhaps someone else can clarify.

Comment: @Brad No actually the decoded strings are different. Strangely, PHP indeed decoded two more characters than Ruby, namely `\xd0\x42` at the end of the string.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but at least one online decoder has trouble with the source string:  http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64decode/  Could you be missing data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decoded in Ruby this comes out to:

```
"9U\x0F\xFC\xF6k/:\x19\xA5\xA7\x90\x81\xAF\xD3\xA4\xAFqx\x90\x0E\xB94\xDBS9\xBD6\x99C\xBA\x14\x942I%>\xD0\xDE\r\x00\xE0\x89\xD5\x04!\x7F\xA2\x8F\x17\xBC"
```

If you're seeing extra characters in PHP it could be because it's not encoded entirely correctly. Decoding and re-encoding this produces a different string:

```
"OVUP/PZrLzoZpaeQga/TpK9xeJAOuTTbUzm9NplDuhSUMkklPtDeDQDgidUE\nIX+ijxe8\n"
```

This differs slightly from your original when it probably shouldn't, and decodes to the same thing.

The `0EI` part could be incomplete and gets rejected by the Ruby decoder.

Comment: Yes you are right. I figured out that I missed '==' in the end of the base 64 encoded string, which is mentioned in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Padding. Thank you pal!

Comment: Somehow PHP automatically fixes the `==`'s.